# Get feature importance with PySpark and XGboost

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, xgboost

I have trained a model using XGboost and PySpark

```
params = { 
    'eta': 0.1,
    'gamma': 0.1,
    'missing': 0.0,
    'treeMethod': 'gpu_hist',
    'maxDepth': 10, 
    'maxLeaves': 256,
    'growPolicy': 'depthwise',
    'objective': 'binary:logistic',
    'minChildWeight': 30.0,
    'lambda_': 1.0,
    'scalePosWeight': 2.0,
    'subsample': 1.0,
    'nthread': 1,
    'numRound': 100,
    'numWorkers': 1,
}

classifier = XGBoostClassifier(**params).setLabelCol(label).setFeaturesCols(features)


model = classifier.fit(train_data)
```

When I try to get the feature importance using

```
model.nativeBooster.getFeatureScore()
```

It returns the following error:

```
Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o2167.getFeatureScore. Trace:
py4j.Py4JException: Method getFeatureScore([]) does not exist
```

Is there a correct way of getting feature importance when using XGboost with PySpark

Answer (score 0):

I am a newbie in this field. I happened to encounter what you are experiencing. You may want to try using: `model.nativeBooster.getScore("", "gain") or model.nativeBooster.getFeatureScore('')`.

My 'model' is of type "sparkxgb.xgboost.XGBoostClassificationModel".

Regards

Comment: However, the result is JavaObject type. How to convert java object to python dict?

Comment: @volity did you figure out how to convert the java object to python dict?